# How to restart oneshot service triggered by timer?

Tags: systemd

I have fairly simple oneshot service. It is triggered by timer. From time to time oneshot service fails due network error. I'm trying to figure out how can oneshot service be restarted in case of failure?

oneshot.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Oneshot Service
Wants=oneshot.timer

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=CONFIG_FILE=/etc/oneshot.conf
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/oneshot ${CONFIG_FILE}

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

oneshot.timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Oneshot timer
Requires=oneshot.service

[Timer]
Unit=oneshot.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:00:00
RandomizedDelaySec=3600

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Seems, Restart option is not legal for oneshot service.

How to restart oneshot service in case of failure?

Comment: Are yo sure about `Restart=on-failure` not being possible? A combination of `Type=oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit=true` should exactly do the trick for you. [See manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#). Could you add how you tried implementing a restart?

Comment: I've added:
```
Restart=on-failure
RemainAfterExit=true
```

After daemon-reload in system status I've got:
```
Apr 26 11:17:16 ip-172-18-7-85.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: oneshot.service has Restart= setting other than no, which isn't allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.
```